# Android application with different data access layer backends

Tags: java, android

I'm working on this project, which basically displays to the client employees data pulled from a client server. I want to have a single front-end code base with a single data access layer, each client will have a different implementation based on his current setup (can be direct database access or some web services etc), this implementation will be developed by the client's in site programmer who have only the dal interface. Which mean that my application doesn't know about the implementation and can only use the interface.

Also my goal is to be able to generate different apks, one for each client using his backend implementation.

1) Is there some android pattern/best practice to follow to develop applications with a  loosely coupled dal implementation?

2) How to setup my environment to automatically do the apks generation?

I've spend hours researching and reading multiple things, and i'm pretty much confused now. I only need some hints to work with.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What You have described is more or less the reason You have interfaces in OOP. You have an interface and You don't care what is behind it You just have to point at right address. I don't fully understand what are You trying to achieve by making a different apk for each client.

Comment: Let's call the app A, the interface I, client one implement I in IX, client two make his specific implementation IY. the setup will generate 2 apks: AX.apk for client one, AY.apk for client two. and each new reversion of my app will have it's own version for each clients backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android pattern for abstracting data sources is [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). As long as you can represent your data as a cursor, you can plug in backends dynamically and bind them using content URI.